# How to plan for change to log backup schedule?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I've looked everywhere but can't find an answer for this. I know it's an easy question, but I want to be sure I don't screw anything up.

I want to change our log backup from every 30 minutes to every 15 minutes. Our logs are growing too fast.

If I change to every 15 minutes, do I have to set a new start time? Currently is showing to start at 12:00 and end at 11:59.

If I change at 10:00 am, will the existing jobs still run until 12:00? or will nothing run until the new start time is hit?

So for example, if I set a new job at 10:00am, would I also need to change the start time to 10:00am?

[image: Screenshot from SSMS]

Answer (score 2):

> If I change to every 15 minutes, do I have to set a new start time?

Nope! The start and end time is when the schedule is *active*. So, assuming you still want to take t-log backups every 15 minutes **all day**, then you just need to adjust that value and the when the next hour/half hour occurs it will take the backup.

> So for example, if I set a new job at 10:00am, would I also need to change the start time to 10:00am?

No - because 10AM is still between 12:00AM and 11:59PM, so the schedule will still be active.

Comment: Wow, dead opposite of what I thought. Really appreciate the answer. Sometimes this easy stuff is the hardest to find!